# How can I view my stored media on my PS3 on my Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, samba, streaming, ps3

I have recently installed Ubuntu Server and setup Samba I believe to use as a general use home server. **How do I go about making this server available to my PS3 so that I can view my stored media on my PS3?**

I enjoy the Ubuntu Server over Ubuntu Desktop because of the wimpy computer specs.
IDK if you need to know the following information, but I will include it anyways.

- Computer is 2.4Ghz
- Only an 80 GB HD (PATA/IDE)
- 512MB DDR RAM
- Ubuntu Server 12.04.4
- Samba v?

I set up an Ubuntu file server using this [Youtube video tuturial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndAYZ0DJ-U4).